# i need to have some assistance with my pyglatin translator code (python)

Tags: python

ok so the code is

```
pyg = 'ay'
def word():
    def new_word():
        new_word = word + first + pyg
print "To translate type A word or name!"
original = raw_input('Enter A word:')
if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    def new_word():
        word = original.lower()
        first = word[0]
        new_word = word[1 : len(new_word)] + first + pyg
    print "Translating 1 moment..."
    print "Translated view below!"
    print new_word
    print "Made by: Tobias Balentine"
else:
    print 'empty'
```

thats my code every thing is working except the part where its supposed to be the translated word ill show you what im getting

```
To translate type A word or name! 
Enter A word:Tobias 
Translating 1 moment... 
Translated view below! 
<function new_word at 0x021619F0> 
Made by: Tobias Balentine
```

so this line (`<function new_word at 0x021619F0>`) is supposed to be the translated word but for some reason its not showing it please help somebody

Comment: Your `new_word` function overwrites your `new_word` variable. Name one of them differently. (You also never invoke your function, so there's that, too.)

Comment: but then it will say what ever i rename one it will say its not defined

Comment: Actually, your whole flow is weird. `def new_word` inside `def word`, when neither is ever used? This can be much simpler...

Comment: well can you help but explain easier i only started learning python 2 weeks ago

Answer (score 0):

```
pyg = 'ay'
print "To translate type A word or name!"
original = raw_input()
if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    word = original.lower()
    first = word[0]
    new_word = word[1:] + first + pyg
    print "Translating 1 moment..."
    print "Translated view below!"
    print new_word
    print "Made by: Tobias Balentine"
else:
    print 'empty'
```

You have way too many functions defined, and you are not even using them.